# How to secure HERE API keys?

Tags: here-api

How to prevent someone just taking my API keys from the client side javascript code and starting to use my HERE subscription for some other use.

I noticed HERE provide an option to secure the API keys for a certain domain on the applications management page: "Secure app credentials against a specific domain".  I have set up this option and also put domain there but I do not see any change on my app behavior.

The application still continue working fine on my PC. Shouldn't the HERE API stop working as web server is running on localhost and not on the defined domain.

My app is running fully on browser, and only static files come from the server (http://localhost:8083/index.html). I am using the HERE javascript API.

I tested also running the app on external cloud service on different domain than localhost. Results are the same. My conclusion is that the setting "Secure app credentials against a specific domain" just has no impact and does not work. Checked also the api response headers and all origins are accepted.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

Answer (score 0):

In your HERE dashboard, you can set the application id and application code to only work on a particular domain or set of domains. If the tokens are fixed to a domain, it won't matter if someone takes your tokens because only the listed domains can use them. If you don't secure the tokens to a domain, then someone will be able to use your tokens if they find them.